# Problem in Map-view in Different Android Mobiles

Tags: android, android-maps

I have developed an Application with new API Key that i got by signing up in

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

with my MD5 that was got from my debug.keystore file

The Code is in the form in xml as given below

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/mapView"
             android:layout_width="500px"
             android:layout_height="600px"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="0db9JFNjg9ytrLCiauBvvfldVQoFAd4pElLltLA"
             />
```

When i install my developed App in SonyXperia mobile , I 'm able to view the Map but in some other mobiles Just Map Gridlines are displayed .

I'm unable to detect what problem. Please provide me the solution for this problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you generate the api key with the debug.keystore?

Comment: Yes ! I generated the Api Key from my debug.keystore

Comment: Are you downloading the APK from Android market or just for testing purpose?

Comment: i just created an Android Project of my Own for displaying Google map but i'm unable to open my Google App in Viewsonic UPC300 2.2 Tablet(Force-closes) but the map is displayed in Sony Xperia .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create your own keystore not the debug.keystore and then after you have obtain your Certificate fingerprint from your own created keystore. This debug.keystore was used for the debugging the application so i think it getting problem. For creating your own keystore just simple first export your application from there you get your keystore. Now use this keystore instead of debug.keystore to object the Certificate fingerprint after you got this generate your map api key and replace it with your or provide this key into your xml file.

Now again re-export your application with your own created keystore and test it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try for it

Comment: i installed the new Apk file generated by new keystore as you told but it doesn't open in Viewsonic Tablet UPC300-2.2.In this tablet it just Force closes while opening the map application